# How to change the id in the <aside> tag on magento content pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml

down vote
favorite
I'm sorting out the blog on my magento based site, currently using an aheadworks extension but moving to wordpress.

Both AW and WP have the sidebar (search, recent posts, etc) in an tag, separate from the actual page content, however AW aside has id="aside" whereas WP aside is id="sidebar", however I can't see where this is set (definitely not in any template files that's for sure, and I can't see anything in wordpress.xml or aw_blog.xml)

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer?

Comment: Hey Julien, I'm the one currently working on this, I'd rather not get our other developer involved.

Comment: I meant, have to try to contact AW?

Comment: They won't answer tech support questions unless you're logged in, and it looked like our developer at the time purchased it under his own account so we don't have an account with the extension as an associated purchase

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, looks like one of our page template phtml files (under template/page/) was using id="aside" while the rest were using id="sidebar".

From this I looked at the wordpress.xml file and changed the template used:

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

to use the template with 'aside:

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Then swapped the reference with the sidebar in it:

```
<reference name="left">
```

to:

```
<reference name="right">
```

in order for it to appear on the correct side